# What is the time 550 minutes after 22:15?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i got this assignment where i need to answer what the time is 550 minutes after 22:15 but the minutes really confuses me.

I got a similar assignment where i had to calculate the time 10000 hours after 16:00 but here i just added the 16 hours to 10000 and looked at at the time 10016 hours after 00 using the residue class [10016]_24 which got me [8]_24 .

How can i do it similar on the first assignment?? We need to use residue classes.

Comment: $550$ minutes is $9$ hours and $10$ minutes

Comment: Just $7:25$, which is $00.15+7.10.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
      15\, &+ 22(60) = \rm\ start\ time\ (mins)\\
+\ \ \  10\, &+\ \ 9(60)  =  550 = \rm\ increment\\
\hline
=\ \  25\, &+ \color{#c00}{31}(60)\\
\equiv\ \  25\, &+ \ \ \color{#c00}7(60)\!\pmod{\color{#c00}{24}(60)}\\[.1em]
{\rm by}\quad\ \  &\color{#c00}{31}\equiv\color{#c00}7\quad\pmod{\color{#c00}{24}}
\end{align}\qquad$$

Answer (score 0):

It's just $00:15$+$7:10=7:25.$